# Communication between multiple user sessions in HTML5 using Windows Azure notification service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, azure

We are building a HTML5 application, we have a need for colloboration between two users the same way as in Google Docs two users can simultaniously edit a document and they can see each others changes.

In our case the document is never stored at server side. And we will only have HTML5 app running in IE10 on XBOX, Windows PC (7 or 8) and Windows Phone (7.5 and 8).

The users will be on same WiFi network.

Where can we find some samples to learn how we can use Windows Azure services/ Mobile services for this scenario.

Thanks,
Navneet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at something like this:
http://laktek.com/2010/05/25/real-time-collaborative-editing-with-websockets-node-js-redis/

For HTML5, you can use Websockets...which can be implemented in Azure using Node.js or using the SignalR (http://signalr.net/) that abstracts websockets/polling in ASP.NET and runs in Windows Azure.

Comment: Thanks Bart for your response, it seems that they use websockets. As I undderstand that WebSockets are available only in Chrome. Is there a solution for IE, I also want the app to run on IE in XBOX.

Comment: SignalR by default uses HTML5 websockets.  If WebSockets are not found it automatically "polyfills" back down to long polling/Ajax requests.  SignalR it was announced will be part of ASP.NET in the future, so my bet would be that this is the way to go for future XBOX support...I would expect an update to the XBOX browser as well for HTML5 features.

Comment: Thanks Bart I tried signalr, it is exactly what I wad looking for.